# How to call a footer section in mylayout.cshtml?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I m working on Template Integration.
First, create a controller HomeController and then create a method

HomeController

```
public ActionResult Footer()  //I create an Individual View from footer
{
   return View();
}
```

Footer.cshtml

```
@section footer
{
  <footer class="footer-area">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               //about us contax us
             </div>
     </div>
    </footer>
}

sharedfolder->create(mylayout.cshtml)
mylayout.cshtml

    <!-- banner post start-->
    <div>
        @RenderBody();      //Dynamic Content
    </div>

    <!-- banner post end-->

    <!-- footer part start-->
      @RenderSection("footer") //error: Section not defined: "footer".
    <!-- footer part end-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Html.Action("Footer", "Home")` in layout
and your foooter.cshtml must be partial view.

Comment: @Nhein ```<h2>Footers</h2>  only header tag will be run

@section footer
{  //not run content inside }   ```

Comment: try remove @section just use <footer> </footer>

Comment: thanks works.  partial view is a blank/empty view. it is a best way to use the Individual partial view for the template integration

Comment: @Nhein it is the best way to use the Individual partial view for the template integration?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Partial View `"_footer.cshtml"` and add the code in that partial view

Then render the footer partial view in the layout page like :

```
@Html.RenderPartial("_footer.cshtml")
```

Comment: MVC give an error:cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult'

Comment: Use @Html.Render("_footer.cshtml")